# Can we download fullphotourl of User Object as jpeg files

Tags: apex, batch

Can we write a batch job to have the fullphotourl be downloaded as jpeg file and stored as a document in salesforce? Does someone have some sample code for it?

Do we need any kind of API call?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty trivial:

```
public class DownloadUserPhotoBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT FullPhotoUrl, Name FROM User]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, User[] scope) {
        Document[] documents = new Document[0];
        for(user u: scope) {
            PageReference ref = new PageReference(u.FullPhotoUrl);
            documents.add(new Document(
                FolderId=UserInfo.getUserId(),
                Name='Photo for '+u.Name,
                Body=ref.getContent()
            ));
        }
        insert documents;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```

There are some caveats that come with this code.

First, the image will be returned as whatever format it is, not necessarily JPEG (e.g. the default image is simply a PNG). You'll need to determine the correct file type and set the ContentType field (not included above).

Second, you'll need to remember that getContent is a callout, so you need to limit your batch size to 100 or less. Depending on the expected data sizes, you might also need to to limit the batch size to a smaller value so as not to hit heap or callout byte limits.

Third, this process is saving all the images to the users "My Documents" folder, so you may need to query the appropriate folder you want to use.